# Get Status of meetings in a channel in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Given a channel-id of a channel is there any endpoint that allows us to query if there is a meeting happening in that channel at the time of the query. Irrespective of whether the meeting was scheduled before or started directly.

From what I have seen so far

`GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages`

Gives the scheduled meeting, but sometimes the meeting may not have started as per time, so how do I know if there is a live meeting (i.e, a meeting has started) in a channel, given its channel-id

Answer (score 1):

The response for the request

```
GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages
```

returns collection of `chatMessage`.

`chatMessage` has a property `eventDetail` of `eventMessageDetail` resource type which represents details of an event that happened in a  channel.

One of the event is `callStartedEventMessageDetail` which represents the details of an event message about call started. This message is generated when a call starts.

`callStartedEventMessageDetail` has a property `callEventType` which represents the call event type. Possible values are: `call`, `meeting`, `screenShare`, `unknownFutureValue`.

So check `eventDetail` if it contains `callStartedEventMessageDetail` with the property `callEventType` set to `meeting`.

Opposite to `callStartedEventMessageDetail` is `callEndedEventMessageDetail` which represents the details of an event message about an ended call

Resources:

[chatMessage resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

[eventMessageDetail resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/eventmessagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[callStartedEventMessageDetail resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callstartedeventmessagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[callEndedEventMessageDetails resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callendedeventmessagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)